# QuickBooks File Upgrade from 2007 to 2019

Tags: quickbooks

I'm looking to upgrade a QuickBooks Pro 2007 file to the Desktop Pro 2019 version. From what I've found on the Intuit forums, it's necessary to either use an upgrade took or trial versions to upgrade the file. Unfortunately, the older versions I am finding on the Intuit website are non-trial versions requiring a license key.

I'd like to perform the upgrade process without a paid support call just to perform the steps listed. Is there a reputable source or Intuit web location for these, or is there a better process to perform?

Proposed upgrade path per QB Forums: 2007 > 2010 > 2013 > 2017 > 2019 via Portable File Format, with incremental .QBB Backups between. Per: [US QuickBooks Community: Conversion](https://quickbooks.intuit.com/community/Questions-about-QuickBooks/Conversion/m-p/161740#M15303)

If I am posting in the wrong Meta, please let me know.

Comment: Good plan. Make multiple backups at each step of the way. Also see https://quickbooks.intuit.com/community/forums/searchpage/tab/message?advanced=false&allow_punctuation=true&filter=location&location=category%3Acommunity-us&q=2007

Comment: Thanks, I added the specific post I found with the proposed path. Unfortunately, there doesn't appear to be too much information, other than trial versions and file convertors -may- exist on the Intuit-side. If I find any breakthroughs on my end I will follow up.